# I am looking for MySQL syntax to copy data between tables with a primary key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one called stock and the other called io_card.

I am trying to copy data from the io_card table into the stock table. The stock table also has a column called quantity.

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stock ("
Part_Number VARCHAR(80) PRIMARY KEY,
Description VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
Value VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
Tolerance INT NOT NULL,
Package VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
Quantity INT);"
```

io_card table has the following fields:

```
Part_Number VARCHAR(80) PRIMARY KEY,
Qty INT
Description VARCHAR(64)
Reference_Designator VARCHAR(64)
Value VARCHAR(64)
Tolerance INT
Package VARCHAR(64)
Manufacturer VARCHAR(128)
Supplier VARCHAR(128)
MOQ INT
```

When I run this query (To prevent Primary Key errors)

```
REPLACE INTO stock
(Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package)
SELECT Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package FROM io_card
```

It erases the stock value stored in the column called quantity in the stock table.

I must copy an entire table across without deleting existing stock supplies in the column called quantity.

I thought that the syntax below would work, but it does not.

```
INSERT INTO stock (Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package)
SELECT Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package FROM io_card
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
Part_Number, 'Part_Number'
Description, 'Description'
Value, 'Value'
Tolerance, 'Tolerance'
Package, 'Package'
```

I am making a simple syntax error - how do I get the actual values from the source table to be copied across? Obviously the statements

```
Part_Number, 'Part_Number'
Description, 'Description'
Value, 'Value'
Tolerance, 'Tolerance'
Package, 'Package'
```

are nonsense, as the field within quotes i.e. 'Part_Number' does not contain a value, and is interpreted as a string.

NOTE: I figured this out.  Here is an example:

INSERT INTO stock (Part_Number, Description, MyValue, Tolerance, Package)

SELECT Part_Number, Description, MyValue, Tolerance, Package FROM excel_io_card

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Part_Number = excel_io_card.Part_Number,

Description = excel_io_card.Description,

MyValue = excel_io_card.MyValue,

Tolerance = excel_io_card.Tolerance,

Package = excel_io_card.Package;

Comment: If you have a question about an error, please include the error message.

Comment: I figured out the query and here is an example:

Comment: Please read [How to format my code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [Can I answer my own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [Voting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Or just [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help), while you're at it. :)

Comment: Sorry if I offended, still trying to find my feet here.

Comment: No offence. Just some well-meant hints.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `VALUES` keyword to get the value that would have been inserted if no duplicate key was was found. This value can then be used in the update:

```
INSERT INTO stock (Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package)
SELECT Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package FROM io_card
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Part_Number = VALUES(Part_Number),
  Description = VALUES(Description),
  Value = VALUES(Value),
  Tolerance = VALUES(Tolerance),
  Package = VALUES(Package)
```

See [VALUES function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)

Comment: Thanks, this works the same as my solution but a lot easier to read. It caters for duplicate keys and does not overwrite existing data. Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE INTO stock(Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package, Quantity) 
SELECT c.Part_Number, c.Description, c.Value, c.Tolerance, c.Package, c.Quantity 
FROM io_card c LEFT JOIN stock s ON c.Part_Number = s.Part_Number
WHERE s.Part_Number IS NULL
```

Or if you need to bring only rows that not present in stock.

```
INSERT INTO stock(Part_Number, Description, Value, Tolerance, Package, Quantity) 
SELECT c.Part_Number, c.Description, c.Value, c.Tolerance, c.Package, 0 
FROM io_card c LEFT JOIN stock s ON c.Part_Number = s.Part_Number
WHERE s.Part_Number IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a very tidy solution.

Comment: I tried your query. I works the first time with an empty table. Then it gives an error message: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '16 PIN BOX HEADER 2.54mm' for key 'PRIMARY' 0.016 sec

Comment: @QuentinJ which one, REPLACE or INSERT?

Comment: @QuentinJ fixed it by adding `WHERE s.Part_Number IS NULL`, here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c888/2).